# Endless code signing issue

Tags: ios, code-signing, provisioning-profile

As it happens once in a while, I am stuck with an app signing issue. Here is the type message I get:

In one case, I get this:

```
Provisioning profile "My_App Development" doesn't include signing certificate "Developer ID Application: My Name (AB22XY77H5)".
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'
```

In another case I get this:

```
A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
```

I have tried a number of things on my own as well as following suggestions from similar post, but to no avail.

One detail, in case that may give a hint to someone, this is an app which has been put on the app store, but then left alone for quite a while.

Is there a clean simple way of getting rid of these endless kind of problems?

Comment: It says, the Profile you are using doesn't have valid certificate, which means the Profile was made using a different certificate than what you are using. You can always create new certificates and profiles, it won't hurt your live app.

Comment: The simple and clean way to get rid of these kinds of problems is to actually read the documentation and understand how code signing works. You're going to keep having problems with this if you just jump to StackOverflow for an answer every time there's a signing issue.

Comment: I guess that is true. I still have to find a clear and precise documentation.
The Apple doc usually being rather good for folks who already know. Not necessarily so good for others.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?  If you are an individual developer (not sharing an enterprise account, for example), I would suggest using automatic code signing settings in Xcode 8.  Even with multiple machines, Apple allows for multiple certs, so each machine could have it's own cert, with a shared provisioning profile.

Comment: I am using Xcode 8.2.1 and I am an individual developer. I have tried both automatic signing and non-automatic signing. Both failed. I think I may have originally signed the provisioning profile with an entity which I have lost, but I am not quite sure. Is there a way to recover things up in such a case. I can always make a new app, with everything (appID and ....) brand new. But in that case, it will not be considered as an update in the appStore I guess.

Comment: If you are having problems, I would suggest deleting all of your certificates for iOS development and deployment, deleting all you profiles under `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/`. Then try automatic signing again.  If you stil have problems, update your question with a screenshot of your project code signing settings.  It's hard to troubleshoot if we can't see your setup.

Comment: You iOS certs can be found in the Keychain Access app.

Comment: Well, I do not find the one I expect. I presume I may have deleted it, thinking I no more needed it.